# How should I mentally parse this statement?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

I encountered the following statement, and mind-farted.

```
++(*q)->len;
```

`q` appears to be a contiguous array of memory, which by the looks of it, 
appears to be an array of pointers to `structs`; getting to grips with a new
code base, sorry for the vagueness.

With the above statement are we
dereferencing `q`, to get the value which is a pointer, which we then dereference and access the field `len`, which we then increment? In code, what i'm trying to say is this `++((*q)->len)`, would be the explicit execution.

Or should I be reading this as, we dereferenced `q` and then incremented the value, which we then dereference and get the `len` field, of the `struct` that is one ahead of `q` before the incrementation. Again, in code, what i'm trying to say is this `(++(*q))->len`, would be the explicit execution.

Any guidance would be grand

UPDATE: 
I guess the first parse makes sense `++((*q)->len)`, as if it was the second case,
we would get the value of `len` and then do nothing with it.

Comment: `++((*q)->len));`

Comment: see the wiki page on [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: Lol, see update. I got there in the end...has been a long day.

Comment: Read [ask], provide a [mcve] and remove the tag of the unrelated language. C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: yes q is basically struct { int len; etc } **q;

Comment: Check out the the C clockwise/spiral rule: http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Comment: @FiddlingBits, the spiral rule is for interpreting declarations, not expressions, and it doesn't even work correctly for all declarations (consider `char **a[3][3]`).  It's easy to construct an *expression* whose correct interpretation is different than the spiral rule would indicate; sticking close to the OP's question, consider `++(*q)->next->len`.  You have to know your operator precedence, or else keep a reference close by.

Comment: the C precedence order will trip you/the code up.  Suggest adding another set of parens, as suggested by @RyanMcCullagh

Answer (score 6):

`*q` doesn't really mean it's contiguous array of memory.
The answer is it increments the `len` field of the structure object at memory location `q`

Comment: He's not inferring it to be a contiguous array based off the statement, though--that's what he's gleaned from the context where he found this statement.

Comment: I know that, I'm telling you that  `q` is pointing to a contiguous array in memory.

Comment: @izaak_pyzaak Rather than describe `q` in words with "appears to be", post could better show what `q` is with code, like its declaration.